# How to count @ of each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the numbers of tags ( like @mark ) in twitter dataset but the problem is that there is some @ without name ( @ )  or the name and the @ are separated  (  @ mike ) that I don't want to count them.

```
NumberOfTags = df2['Tweet'].str.count('@')
```

the table :

| idTweet | tweet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | @mike is my friend and @emilie is not |
| 2 | @ jordan look at this post and share it with @daniel @ @ @ |

Answer (score 2):

[pandas.Series.str.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) supports regex syntax

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'Tweet': {
            1: '@mike is my friend and @emilie is not',
            2: '@ jordan look at this post and share it with @daniel @ @ @', }
    }
)

df['NumberOfTags'] = df['Tweet'].str.count('@\w+')
```

Result is

| Tweet | NumberOfTags |
| --- | --- |
| @mike is my friend and @emilie is not | 2 |
| @ jordan look at this post and share it with @daniel @ @ @ | 1 |

Comment: thanks that answer my question